# Why is there an inconstancy between these two ways of plotting a function in Octave?

Tags: plot, octave, scilab

## Context

I have a function named `ibm` that I defined with a simple if condition: it should be 0 until a certain value (500), then is linear after that value:

```
function f = ibm(x)
  if(nargin != 1)
    usage("ibm(x)");
  endif
  if(x <= 500)
    f = 0;
  else
    f = (x-500) *0.02;
  endif
endfunction
```

Then in a script, I wanted to plot this function with x in range from 0 to 1000, so I tried to plot it with a simple

```
x=0:1:1000;
plot(x,ibm(x));
```

But the result did not show what I wanted: it showed a linear function without a flat part (see figure 1, the red graph). It did NOT correspond to the function results, and I checked some values below 500: if I type `ibm(34)` the result is 0 as expected, but not in the graph.
**Why this discrepancy?**

So after a while puzzling over this issue, I tried adding the result values "manually" in a for loop, and then the result became what I expected (see figure 2, the blue graph).

### A complete code sample (MVE) here:

This produces both figures (wrong and right) with the same function ibm.

```
1; # start of file should not start with function, so useless statement here
# The function we want to plot
function f = ibm(x)
  if(nargin != 1)
    usage("ibm(x)");
  endif
  if(x <= 500)
    f = 0;
  else
    f = (x-500) *0.02;
  endif
endfunction

# For figure 1, directly computed (wrong plot result, in red)
x=0:1:1000;
figure(1);
plot( x, ibm(x), "xr");
xlabel("x");
ylabel("ibm(x)");
title("ibm(x) directly computed");
legend("ibm(x)");

# for figure 2, in for loop (correct plot result, in blue)
a = [];
for(i=x)
  a = [a, ibm(i)];
end
figure(2);
plot(x,a, "ob");
xlabel("x");
ylabel("ibm(x)");
title("ibm(x) in for loop");
legend("ibm(x)");
```

## Question

**Why the 1st (and most straightforward) method doesn't produce the graph result that I want?** Should I always plot graphs with a for loop? It's as if the plot function doesn't take into account the `if(x <= 500)` and goes straight to the linear part.

As a note, I even tried the 1st way of plotting with Scilab, and ended up with the same result (red wrong curve), and I still don't know why.

## Figures

### Wrong

[image: Function shown is linear and does not correspond to function output]

### Right

[image: Correctly plotted function (with manual for)]

Comment: Just adding that your RELU can be rewritten easily without an if statement as `f = @(x) max( 0, x - 500 * 0.02 )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your definition of `ibm`. You only coded it for a `x` of length 1. What does the code do for `ibm([0,1000])`? How does the `if` condition react to that `x`?

I think this is a confusion of how does vectorization occurs. Octave will not call 1000 `ibm` each with its own individual `x`, but will call `ibm` once with all 1000 `x` as input. How you deal with vector inputs its on you, and your function simply doesn't.

for example, if you replace the `if` with:

```
 f = (x-500) *0.02;
 f(x<500) = 0 ;
```

the function should work (and therefore the plot should work), as both of those lines are vectorized and work for any size of `x`.

---

If you want more info, check [octaves manual for `if`](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/The-if-Statement.html).

> The condition in an *if* statement is considered true if its value is
> nonzero, and false if its value is zero. If the value of the
> conditional expression in an *if* statement is a vector or a matrix, it
> is considered true only if it is non-empty and *all* of the elements are
> nonzero. The conceptually equivalent code when *condition* is a matrix
> is shown below.
>
> `if (matrix) ≡ if (all (matrix(:)))`